# Bounds on an additive combinatorics problem (just looking for references)

Tags: additive-combinatorics

I'm looking for known results of a problem, but i don't know the right terms to look for.

What is the minimal number $a$, s.t. any subset $A\subseteq \mathbb{Z}_3^n$  $\ \ \ |A|\ge a$,  contains  3 distinct elements $x,y,z$ satisfying $x+y+z=0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the term you are looking for is "zero sums", or similar variants.  See e.g. [This article](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X94003086).

Theorem 2.5 seems relevant. It is attributed to Harboth, and states
that if $f(m,d)$ is the minimal length of a sequence necessary to guarantee a zero-sum in $\mathbb Z_m^d$, then $(m-1)2^d + 1 \leq f(m,d) \leq (m-1)m^d +1$.